# How to use audio port only for input?

Tags: sound

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed in my lenovo. I have a single audio port that serves for both input and output. If I have a headphone with mic connected how do I make the computer take input from the mic but use the external speakers for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GNOME audio settings are controlled by the GNOME Control Center

`gnome-control-center sound`

You can set the inputs & outputs you desire in the corresponding tabs.

[image]

Another handy audio deivce manager that has more vebose features is [Pulse Audio Volume Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/) which can be directly installed from the Ubuntu store or by:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pavucontrol paman`